# How to fix “missing return statement” in a for loop when trying to return individual objects in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am doing a project for school that requires us to use arrays to put 'Spherocylinder' objects within the array.
A spherocylinder object consists of (String label, double edge, double height)

I am trying to create a method that takes a (String labelIn) parameter and find a spherocylinder object that matches the parameter given and return it

```
public Spherocylinder findSpherocylinder(String labelIn) {
        
      for (int i = 0; i < spObjects; i++) {
         if (sList[i].getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(labelIn)) {
            return sList[i];
         }
         else {
            return null;
         }
      }
   }
```

It gives me a missing return statement and don't know how I would go about moving the return to outside of the 'for' statement. The project states that if no object is found to match the parameter it must return 'null'

Comment: Just get rid of the `else` clause (which is wrong anyway as it will return on the first failure instead of if they all fail) and move the `return null` after the `for` loop

Comment: Code outside the for loop should return something, otherwise if value of spObjects is < 0 when method findSpherocylinder is called, it doesnt return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the else from the for loop and put the return statement outside the loop.

```
public Spherocylinder findSpherocylinder(String labelIn) {
    
  for (int i = 0; i < spObjects; i++) {
     if (sList[i].getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(labelIn)) {
        return sList[i];
     }
  }

  return null;
}
```

The reason for this is that there might be a case where the for loop may not run even once so the function cannot return anything in that case. Compiler detects this and hence gives an error. It is unlike python where by default function returns a None.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use reduction like this :

```
public Spherocylinder findSpherocylinder(String labelIn) {
        return sList.stream()
                .filter(spherocylinder -> spherocylinder.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase(labelIn))
                .reduce((a, b) -> {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Multiple elements: " + a + ", " + b);
                })
                .get();
    }
```

This obtains the sole matching element from the stream, throwing

```
NoSuchElementException in case the stream is empty, or
IllegalStateException in case the stream contains more than one matching element.
```